# Make Jenkins Build a SUCCESS After successful Spring-boot run

Tags: maven, spring-boot, jenkins

I have CI system using Jenkins that automatically clones a repository,
then runs `mvn clean install` and then `mvn spring-boot:run` (using windows batch).

My problem is that the Jenkins Build does not stop even though the `spring-boot:run` is successful.

Is there any way to work this out?

Comment: are you trying to build OR deploy your spring-boot project?

Comment: I was trying to deploy a spring-boot project

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this.

I added a Build Step that executes a Windows Batch file as a child process
but before starting the batch process, I changed the BUILD_ID to something like BUILD_ID='NO_DELETE' so that Jenkins won't automatically kill it.